# Visual Studio 2015 - Check TFS Connection

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

I have opened an existing solution with **Visual Studio 2015**, I compiled it and I run it in order to test if all works properly or not... All was ok.

Then I want to move it so **TFS Online** in order to implement some changes and manage versioning.

I just make a right click on the solution and selected "**Add to source Control**"...

It automatically added the solution to source control but I don't know where...

It didn't asked me the place to put the solution...
Now it seems to be connected to a GIT repository...

How can I check in which project the solution is attached ?
And how can I switch the solution place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t connect to anything in Team Explorer, it will create a local repository when you click Add to source control.

If you connect to a local git repository and the solution is in the corresponding working folder (repository folder), it will add the solution to that repository when click Add to source control, otherwise it will create a new local repository.

You can check the log in Output windows of VS (change Show output from to Source Control-Git)

Since you want to add the files to VSTS (TFS online), you can open Team Explorer and connect to your VSTS, then right click the solution > Add to source control.